As a policy, should acceptance comments be edited into answers on abandoned [story-identification] posts?
It's unfortunately common that story-identification answers get a comment (or non-answer) along the lines of "Thanks, this is the one!" instead of the author formally accepting them. These comments may get deleted (in some cases with a single flag), which is essentially impossible to prevent and leaves almost no trace. For context, see PSA: it's now possible for moderators to undelete comments that weren't mod-deleted.
There's one thing that the community can do to prevent this information from being lost: Edit the acceptance into the correct answer. Even something as simple as "accepted by user123" with a link to the comment would work. This would also work when OP posts the informal acceptance in a (non-)answer, since those have to be deleted. As another bonus, this could be useful when searching.
These edits would only need to happen on questions without a formal accepted answer that look abandoned, namely those from new users that haven't visited since leaving the comment. The message can be edited out of the answer if formal acceptance is given afterwards.
As an aside, we would have to follow the rules for not bumping too many old posts at once if this becomes policy.
Should this become policy?

"This would also work when OP posts the informal acceptance in a (non-)answer, since those have to be deleted." I encourage users to flag for a moderator instead of voting to delete such posts, and I happily convert them to a comment on the answer that should be accepted.

Editing in acceptance information to a post strikes me as an abuse of the editing privilege, even if well-meaning. I'd much prefer to see a solution which only used comments to indicate acceptance in the absence of the actual check mark. As a moderator I do post a comment indicating acceptance whenever I come across a situation in which acceptance is not readily apparent (not just deleted acceptance comments, but also in other cases where only moderators can see something that indicates acceptance by the OP).

Interesting proposal, but I agree with @Null. It's not a big workload for mods to undelete comments or post confirmation ourselves. I'm imagining a policy as you suggest could be abused: (1) what checks and balances would stop someone claiming their answer was unofficially accepted when it wasn't? would you flag every such edit for mods to check if you can't see a comment from the OP? (2) when do we decide the OP isn't coming back and an edit should be made? We already see borderline aggressive badgering of OPs in comments to accept, suggesting some answerers are desperate for confirmation.

@Randal'Thor What we're doing right now (eg having thank you comments that shouldn't be flagged and even the idea of a question that cannot be canonically answered by the community) is already against SE norms. That's why it only takes one flag to delete many of these comments. The fact is that while it takes 3 seconds to undelete a comment on a flagged post, there's no way to ensure that posts with deleted acceptance comments get flagged for that process to even occur.

@Randal'Thor 1) I don't think there needs to be much in the way of checks and balances. Lying about that would be antisocial behavior with basically no benefit, and any cursory glance from a mod would reveal it. Handle it the same way as any other troublemaking (message/suspension). 2) I'm leaving this up to discussion, though I'm not sure we need an exact number (ie use your judgment and revise the policy later if needed).

It only solves a subset of the possible cases, but perhaps we could suggest that people closing comment-accepted story-id questions as duplicate add the comment ID to the close reason?

@DavidW That's a good idea!

@DavidW Yes, that is an excellent idea, which I will try to remember to implement in the future when closing such questions!

In general I'm against leaving any sort of meta-commentary cluttering the body of the question, regardless of why it's there. That includes comments about why a particular edit was made, thanking users for their edits or any sort of notes answering comments.

If an 'acceptance comment' is sitting there unmolested below the question, just leave it alone. Most of these comments stay quite happily there for years without anyone flagging them, and with no need to do anything.
If you suspect that an acceptance comment has been deleted (for example if a gold tag user has marked it as a dupe for no obvious reason that you can discern), the appropriate thing to do is to flag the question for a moderator to investigate. If they discover a deleted comment, they can undelete it.

How do you know there's a deleted comment there?

@Laurel - If you didn't know there was a deleted comment, why would you be editing in that there's a deleted comment?

@Laurel - That being said, sometimes there are clues, like that an experienced user (someone who should and does know better) has marked this as a dupe.

You would edit in the comment before it gets deleted, which would be a clue for all questions, not just the ones that are eligible as duplicates (which is fairly rare, about 10%).

@Laurel - That's a terrible idea and what I'm arguing against.

I get that what I'm suggesting goes against how things are usually done on SE, but you've not actually given any reason why it's "a terrible idea". The reasoning behind barring other edits ("update" being redundant w/edit history & "thanks" being a social nicety that adds nothing else) does not apply here. In fact, my suggestion closely aligns with other SE rules (ie, important content should not be put just in a comment).

@Laurel - Because it clutters the question with unneeded crap

Although, as one of those "experienced users", I will have to admit that I don't always know what I am doing. :-D

@FuzzyBoots - Yeah, but there's a lot of people watching what other people are doing. Even fairly prolific editors like myself occasionally make mistakes and others aren't generally afraid to point that out.

Yes, that seems reasonable
When I post an answer to a story ID request and the querant lets me know that it's not what they were looking for, I often edit my answer to include a short note to indicate it's not the right answer. I do this as a courtesy to other users, to let them know they could try their hand at answering too, and to allow them to cast an informed vote.
I don't see any difference with an affirmative comment. Of course, we would prefer an accepted answer, but in lieu of that, this would be the next best thing.
It would mean having answer and confirmation tied as closely together as possible in absence of that green check mark. And while comments of this kind aren't deleted that often, comments still are considered transient.
